# Refreshing data without reloading

Tags: asp.net, refresh, reload, page-refresh

I want to refresh data in ASP.NET without reloading page.
If it is possible I don't want to use AJAX.

I am interesting in clearly .NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [PokeIn](http://pokein.com/Help/BasicTutorial.aspx) a Comet implementation for ASP.NET

You can also use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) which is officially supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use AJAX you can use JQuery  to do an Async Http request and refresh only the portion of the page you are interested in (Partial Rendering).

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

you can't refresh a portion of the page without using any client side framework (lots of years ago when JQuery was not out yet and JavaScript was not used we were using IFrame to achieve that but today would be really bad)

Comment: While I agree with you, jQuery.Get/Post is still using Ajax in the back-end. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ says "This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:$.ajax({});" I mean, I don't see how else he will accomplish this without Ajax at the end, I just wanted to point out that JQuery and UpdatePanel as someone mentioned before still use Ajax.

Comment: I was talking about Microsoft Ajax.Anyway Ajax is for asynchronous JavaScript and XML so it is just acronym that maybe today is overused.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UpdatePanel` to refresh your data.

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/